Create an ahkv2 hotkey that triggers an existing hotkey that uses lctrl
Pressing "b" should trigger the hotkey for "leftControl+7"
<^7:: send "success" ;left ctrl 7

b::{
    send "<^7" ;not working;  send "^7" will work for ctrl 7
}

Instead it recognizes < as a character. You put it in {<} still a character, you put it like {<^}, it doesn't recognize. And you can't send "{lctrl down}7{lctrl up}".
To be clear: the answer must differentiate between the left and right control keys. You may assume right control is already in use for a separate hotkey.
